# Expression to Change Background colour if twice the 10 day average

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I've got this expression in a report:

```
=iif(
SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) >
    (
    SUM(iif
        (
        Fields!Date.Value >= DateAdd("d",-10,TODAY())
        ,Fields!Amount.Value
        ,CDbl(0)
        )) / 10
    )*2.0,
"Gold",
"Transparent"
)
```

It is controlling a table's text box background colour.

I was hoping it would change the cell to gold if the amount in the cell is twice, or more, than the 10 day average for that specific row.

The table shows 10 days of data and the dataset it uses has 60 days of data in it, so 10 day averages should be available.

Is the expression incorrect?

This is what it is currently creating - the two rows that are completely orange are obviously not what I want.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have DateAdd("d",-30,TODAY())? I thought you are only comparing it to the average of the 10 days?

Comment: @mmarie apologies - typo: the expresssion used says 10. I've ended up adding another column TenDayAvg to my `DataSet` and therefore simplifying this expression to compare to that column - the formatting works now .....but I'm still interested to know why the above fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the sum you are doing to create your average. It is really only summing the first number it encounters and then dividing by 10 and multiplying by 2.  You need to change the scope of your sum to the entire dataset.  Here's how I proved this out.

I took the second row of numbers in your table above as my example.  Here's my query.

```
SELECT        '1/15/14' AS dt, 1 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/16/14' AS dt, 7 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/17/14' AS dt, 5 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/18/14' AS dt, 6 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/19/14' AS dt, 4 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/20/14' AS dt, 5 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/21/14' AS dt, 5 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/22/14' AS dt, 5 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/23/14' AS dt, 6 AS value
UNION
SELECT        '1/24/14' AS dt, 6 AS value
```

I created a tablix with dt in the columns value in the data. If I take your average calculation and put it in a row below, it will return 9.8 for every column.

I first used your fill expression to make sure I got the same results as you.  Then I altered it to get the correct answer:

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!value.Value) >  
(Sum(iif(Fields!dt.Value >= Dateadd("d",-10, today()), Fields!value.Value, CDbl(0)), "DataSet1")/10) * 2,
"Gold","White")
```

With the data I had, none of the cells should turn gold, and that is the result I got.  If I change the value for 1/15 to 20 and then preview my table, that cell turns gold because 69/10*2 = 13.8 and 20 > 13.8.

Comment: +1 excellent - is this extra scope argument available for all the aggregate functions? One thing that is a little odd - you say (and I believe you) "it is really only summing itself and then dividing by 10 and multiplying by 2" ....if this was true then surely my screenprint should show **no** gold cells?

Comment: The scope argument is available for the other aggregations as well.  here's a [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255275.aspx#CalculatingAggregates) where you can see it. I updated my answer to be more accurate to address the second question.  It's not summing only that number, it just sums the first number of the set that it encounters.